# SQL Pivot / Line Item Reporting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to writing queries in SQL Server.  I am struggling with how to create a line item report that is broken out by a couple different paritions.  For example, my STARTING data sample would look like:

```
pdheeid         pdhcoid pdhpaygroup Union Code  pdhdedcode  pdheecuramt pdhpaydate
AJ5PTN0000K0    BWC0O   8F          Union(Y/N)  U5018       3.15        2018-01-05 00:00:00.000
AJ5PTN0000K0    BWC0O   8F          Union(Y/N)  U5018       3.15        2018-01-19 00:00:00.000
AJ5PTN0000K0    BWC0O   8F          Union(Y/N)  U5018       3.15        2018-02-02 00:00:00.000
AJ5PTN0000K0    BWC0O   8F          Union(Y/N)  U5018       3.15        2018-02-16 00:00:00.000
AJ5PTN0000K0    BWC0O   8F          Union(Y/N)  U5018       3.15        2018-03-02 00:00:00.000
AJ5Q1U0000K0    BWC0O   8G          Union(Y/N)  U5018       3.01        2018-01-05 00:00:00.000
AJ5Q1U0000K0    BWC0O   8G          Union(Y/N)  U5018       3.01        2018-01-19 00:00:00.000
AJ5Q1U0000K0    BWC0O   8G          Union(Y/N)  U5018       3.01        2018-02-02 00:00:00.000
AJ5Q1U0000K0    BWC0O   8G          Union(Y/N)  U5018       3.01        2018-02-16 00:00:00.000
AJ5Q1U0000K0    BWC0O   8G          Union(Y/N)  U5018       3.01        2018-03-02 00:00:00.000
```

From there, I am looking to do an almost pivot of sorts, to get a detail output that would be like:

```
PayDate    Pay Group    Union Code    Total Transactions    Unique Employees  Deduction Code    Sum(dollars for group)  Avg(across employees in the group)
```

Then be able to roll it up by year, which would be more like:

```
YEAR(PayDate)   Pay Group    Union Code    Total Transactions    Unique Employees  Deduction Code    Sum(dollars for group)  Avg(across employees in the group)
```

Sorry for the noob questions, I am new to the SQL world and still trying to get up to speed.

Comment: It sounds like you're describing a straightforward `GROUP BY` query rather than a `PIVOT`.  Can you clarify which columns are part of your group and which are being aggregated?  I'd guess that `PayDate`, `Pay Group`, `Union Code`, and `Deduction Code` are your `GROUP BY` columns, and the rest are aggregates.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I am using your column "names" that you provided in your detail output. Sorry for not answering your question completely. This would not provide the unique employees in a grouping, but i hope it is a starting point.

```
select 
PayDate ,   
Pay Group ,   
Union Code  ,  
count(transactions) as Total Transactions
count(employees) as  non-unique employees **
Deduction Code    
Sum(dollars) as dollars for group
Avg(dollars) as across employees in the group
from some_table
group by
PayDate ,   
Pay Group ,   
Union Code  ,  
Deduction Code
```